# rsync: notify of any files that were skipped

Tags: rsync, file-copy

I am using the following `rsync` command which includes the "update" option, meaning it will skip files at the receiver which are newer. It works, except that I need it to tell me the **files which were skipped** because they are newer on the receiver.

```
rsync -ahHX --delete --itemize-changes --stats --update /path/to/source/ --exclude=/dir1/ --exclude=/dir2/ --exclude=/dir3/ /path/to/receiver/
```

I have reviewed the man page and I don't see such an option. I hope I just missed it or didn't understand something.

If rsync will not do this, what other tools can I use? I tried `diff -rqw /path/to/source/ /path/to/receiver/` but that takes far too long. It is doing more than I need.

The total file size is 24.60 GB in 71,835 files.

Comment: Seems like a script that compares the last modified times of source files with receiver files is all you need there. That's assuming there is no rsync feature that does what you want. In perl File::Find plus File::stat would be all you'd really need there, plus a loop to do the checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope there is a better solution, but this is what I came up with:

First, run this check in the opposite direction of my copy operation:

```
rsync --dry-run -ahvP --itemize-changes --stats /path/to/receiver/ /path/to/source/
```

**That will tell me which files are newer on the receiver** (and will therefore be skipped by my rsync command). I can manually address those files, then run my original rsync command:

```
rsync -ahHX --delete --itemize-changes --stats --update /path/to/source/ --exclude=/dir1/ --exclude=/dir2/ --exclude=/dir3/ /path/to/receiver/
```

This accomplishes my goal, but it involves waiting for rsync to make the file list twice. It takes about 15 seconds each time. I can live with that if there is no better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could add in two levels of verbosity.

```
$ rsync -a --update -vv a/ b/
sending incremental file list
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
1 is uptodate
2 is uptodate
3 is newer
4 is uptodate
5 is newer
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0
```

Comment: As noted in the question, "The total file size is 24.60 GB in 71,835 files." Adding more verbosity results in obfuscating any useful messages due to the output message volume being massive.

Comment: Yup, it sucks as opposed to being visible in something like the `itemize-changes` output.  But that's the only one-pass way I see to pull the information.  It is potentially filterable though.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.